# A simple probability question about distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is my question:
A student solves problems every day. On average, he solves 7 problems per day. What is a probability distribution of number of solved problem per day.

Is it Poisson ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which chapter of which book are you picking up this problem from?

Comment: Why does it matter ?

Comment: It matters because the chapter must be introducing the kind of distribution that you are supposed to use. Look, it usually is the Poisson random variable (of mean $7$ in this case), because this student only probably does a non-negative integer number of problems in a day, but I just asked to be fully sure. For all we know, John could be doing exactly $7$ problems each day.

Comment: There is no information given regarding the distribution.  It could be a constant.  He could alternate between $6$ and $8$, or between $0$ and $14$.  And so on.  Poisson is possible, of course, but it is not determined.  That is, a distribution is not uniquely determined by its mean.

Comment: But if it said by average, then it implies that is not constant. Isn't a typical Poisson problem is the number of calls per hour to a call-center is X?

Comment: @John I admit I was being too skeptical. It probably is the Poisson random variable with mean $7$, and I apologize for beating around the bush. The only thing I was worried about is misleading you with a wrong choice of random variable while the person who wrote the question expected a different choice of random variable. There are many other random variables which are concentrated on the non-negative integers, but this one screams Poisson, like you say.

Comment: This is a basic probability course. So, the choice is between Uniform, Binomial, Geometric, Poisson and Normal. So, it seems that Poisson is indeed the only option. Thanks!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon took me a while. I watched the first few seasons  +++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teresa_Lisbon  +++  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mentalist

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for watching, Lisbon is my role model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

You can set $X$ as the number of problems solved per day and it makes sense that its distribution is represented by a poisson.

In particular:

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\frac{e^{-7}7^x}{x!}$$

$x=0,1,2,3...$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate!